# Why wont heroku let me use my own sendgrid account?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, sendgrid-rails

Why won't heroku let users use their own sendgrid accounts?

I installed sendgrid addon to heroku with following command:

```
heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
```

and when i log into my dashboard heroku creates me a starter account. How do i use my own sendgrid account that I already have and tested on my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku won't prevent you from using your own sendgrid account. You can set your own [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to setup the credentials of any account you wish.

For example:

> heroku config:set SENDGRID_ID=abcd SENDGRID_TOKEN=efgh

Those two config vars will then be available to your app as environment variables.
Provisioning the add-on will only attach a new sendgrid account to your heroku account, and automatically set the config vars. But nothing prevents you from doing that yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. However, should I keep the sendgrid addon on my heroku account, or....delete it? Because I notice every time i try to log into sendgrid it sends me to a default starter account heroku sets up for users.

Comment: Unless you're using it, you can delete it.